# How to decode a two bit signal into one-hot encoding, with 7400 series ICs?

Tags: digital-logic

Is there a single 7400 series IC which does this directly?

(I know can do this with 4*NOT + 4*AND gates, but that will be 2 ICs.)

Truth table:

```
 in | out
h l | 3 2 1 0
----+--------
0 0 | 0 0 0 1
0 1 | 0 0 1 0
1 0 | 0 1 0 0
1 1 | 1 0 0 0
```

(I'm not looking to mux/demux a signal.)

Comment: _2_ inverters and 4 ANDs.

Comment: If you can use CMOS instead of bipolar, a 74HC4052 would work for you, and maybe a CD4052B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. The chip you want is known as a decoder. Specifically, you are looking for a 2-to-4 decoder, or 1-of-4 decoder.

A cursory glance at the [7400 series logic list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits) suggests that a [74139](http://susta.cz/fel/74/pdf/sn_74139.pdf) would work for you, it's actually a dual 2-to-4 decoder.

Most decoders will have an enable input, from your truth table, it appears you don't need this, so you can simply tie it to whichever voltage is enable (most enables are active low, so you would tie it low).

If a '139 doesn't work or is difficult to source:

- ['138](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mcclurel/sn74ls138rev5.pdf): 1-of-8 decoder (just ignore four of the outputs and one of the inputs)
- ['156](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls156.pdf): dual 2-to-4 decoder/demux.
- etc.

However, as long as you don't need teeny-tiny packages, [Digikey has '139s](https://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?keywords=74ls139) in SOIC and DIP.

---

Edit: as Chris Stratton pointed out, these devices have active low outputs (the selected line is low while all others are high). If your downstream logic cannot deal with this, the '239 is probably what you are looking for. It's the same as '139, except with active-high outputs.

Unfortunately, these are not as easy to find in stock. The ['238](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74ac238.pdf) can be found on [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/CD74AC238M96/296-4239-1-ND/375125), albeit the 74AC family version.

Comment: Close, but these devices are active low - quite useful for driving the chip select of comparable vintage bus peripherals, but the opposite of the posted truth table.  Perhaps they can adapt to work with it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my answer with the active high versions, which are much harder to obtain.

Comment: Another fairly rare part, and 24 pin... MM74HC4514

Answer (score 1):

If you've got some glue logic laying around you can do it like this:

[image]

Comment: how about with 3 inputs - just use 3 input AND gates at the outputs ?